# Move div from one place to another in jQuery

Tags: jquery

we have some javascript that we have no control over. I need to move it from one place to another and am wondering if this is possible:

```
......

    <div class='af-row'>
      <div class='af-header af-mh-123'>
          here is my info
       </div>
    </div>

......

.......
 <div class='new-place'></div>
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var $tmp=$('.af-mh-123').parent().???;
$('.af-mh-123').parent().remove();
$('.new-place').html($tmp);
```

but obviously doesn't work. Is this possible?

so that end result is:

```
 <div class='new-place'>
    <div class='af-row'>
      <div class='af-header af-mh-123'>
          here is my info
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

pretty straightforward.

Comment: What is `.af-mh-123`? Also, what is the end goal?

Comment: You want to move the javascript? Do you mean execute it in some other moment?

Comment: Why not just do `$('.new-place').append($('.af-mh-123').parent());`?

Comment: it's really obvious what I"m trying to do.

Comment: are these repeating elements? Does new place exist?  `obvious` is not always so

Comment: @timpone No, it isn't clear at all. And saying it's clear instead of answering our doubts doesn't help.

Comment: I couldn't amke it any clearer than I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even your solution is working. Just without the `???`.

See this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/8MKc4/

Comment: so we're actually loading it externally - I think this is beyond jquery to be honest. I had tried getScript - but I think you are right.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
$('.af-mh-123').parent().appendTo(".new-place");
```